# Update style from Word template

Tags: c#, ms-word

I generate a Word document using c#.

I want to apply a template to the written document. I do that like:

```
object oTemplate = (object)coverPagePath;
wordApp.ActiveDocument.set_AttachedTemplate(ref oTemplate);
wordApp.ActiveDocument.UpdateStyles();
```

But the headings styles still are not completely updated! Only Heading 1 is as the template Heading 1 style.

Comment: AFAIK each style will only update if it is listed in the template as "In Use". You can ensure that it is "In Use" by creating a paragraph of that style in the template, then deleting it.